# How can we apply group/user settings to Chrome managed browsers, along with OU?

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace

We are in the process of starting to use Chrome managed browsers, and for that we're using enrollment tokens from our MDM solution.

We have automation in place that moves browsers to their users' corresponding Organizational Units, and applying settings to these OUs works just fine.

The problem is that we would like to make certain extensions available to certain groups (or even users) and that simply doesn't seem to have any effect.

We tried allowing users to sign in to Chrome but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Anyone else experienced that as well?